# Executable linking/loading workflow

Tags: operating-systems, compilers, virtual-memory

I'm having a bad time understanding how multiple concepts work simultaneously for achieving linking/loading correctly an executable.

From the very beginning loading/linking is basically the art of putting another layer of abstraction over concrete memory addresses to achieve using the same piece of code over multiple executables (could be a shared lib linked to multiple binaries, an external library statically added in your code or even the same instance of a program under different memory assumptions like virtual memory|overlays and so on).

See [Relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) wikipedia article, it explicitly states `Relocation is the process of assigning load addresses for position-dependent code` while [Linkers & Loaders](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzaceaaso2ra6py425w3pus6g7w4ldvwkmja4vmgaaun4vfbttxypbk26?filename=Levine%2C%20John%20R%20-%20Linkers%20and%20loaders-Morgan%20Kaufmann%20%282010%29.pdf) states `Relocation is the process of assigning load addresses to the various parts of the program, adjusting the code and data in the program to reflect the assigned addresses`. Question is my common sense says to me that relocation should not be tied to position dependent/independent code since always you need to attach concrete addresses to a program formed by multiple subprograms (let's say libraries), isn't it?. Also relocation is tied (as my current undestanding is) to linking while position independent(ness?) should be a loader concept since the idea is using a program regardless where the OS put it on RAM. Now second question is, how does position independent code works along virtual memory because for me seems like virtual memory solves the problem of loading stuff wherever you want (maybe not security issues though).

Let's keep going, while watching [ASLR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urLyBNnqeUA&t=12s) it shows [Program possible load scenarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpQWJ.png) as a way to randomize how stuff is put on the RAM at runtime. Multiple questions arise from here

- The usual understanding of the heap/stack is broken, isn't the stack should be in decreasing order and the heap in increasing order (to avoid collisions between them)?. How is this handled now and how does it affect paging? (I imagine that a `random` layout would inevitable lead to ask pages to the OS quicker than the old classical layout, maybe I'm wrong)
- This seems to need another relocation step(s?) here in order to fulfill loading a program which previously was statically understood (talking about layout without counting shared stuff) but in the fly was loaded totally different. How does this relates to position independent code?

There is a great resource on virtual memory, see [Architecture and operating system support for virtual memory](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzaceachr46ymghisubv5bledpohniwlww667yvjg3msz6pfz66t2fhua?filename=%28synthesis%20lectures%20on%20computer%20architecture%29%20Abhishek%20Bhattacharjee%2C%20Daniel%20Lustig%20-%20Architecture%20and%20operating%20system%20support%20for%20virtual%20memory-Morgan%20Claypool%20%282018%29.pdf), but I might be not fully understanding how this play around with linking/loading (and the concepts above PIC/ASLR) in the big picture on a per process basis. I need help here because I'm a little bit lost (just began with malware analysis stuff that's why I'm interested in this low level stuff), if someone is able to help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  We are a question-and-answer forum, so we require you to articulate a single question.  Each post should contain only a single question.  If you have multiple questions, they should be posted separately.  This site's format isn't a good fit for "I'm generally lost here, can you explain the entire topic to me?".  Our goal is to build up an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, in the form of a question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge number of questions here, so I'm going to go through what I think the central question is, and try to come up with a reasonably self-contained answer that, I hope, addresses what you wanted to know.

Here's the important point: Executable files are typically loaded at a known virtual address, but DSOs (dynamic shared objects, think `.dll` on Windows or `.so` on Unix) are typically not.

The clue is in the word "shared"; the same DSO can be shared between multiple running programs. Moreover, you cannot statically assign load addresses to all DSOs without knowing which executables will load which DSOs in advance. Application plugins are the obvious case in point.

Thanks to the virtual memory system, the same DSO may be loaded at different virtual addresses in different running programs, and the physical memory for any static information (e.g. program text) will be shared between them. And thanks to large 64-bit address spaces and ASLR (address space layout randomisation), they usually *are* loaded at different virtual addresses.

This means that at link time, an executable can have all of its global names resolved to a known virtual address, but a DSO cannot.

There are two interesting cases: references from *code*, and references from *static data*.

For references that are entirely within a DSO (i.e. referencing a global name within the DSO from within the same DSO) in code, you can usually write position-independent code on most modern CPUs, but how exactly this is achieved depends on the kind of reference, the ABI, and the architecture.

Just as an example of that last point, 32-bit Intel-esque CPUs have a PC-relative call instruction, but no PC-relative load/store instruction, so while calling functions within the DSO can be resolved at link time, loading and storing static data cannot. Different ABIs handle this in different ways, such as reserving a register to point to an appropriate location in the data segment, or using the Apple solution of loading the instruction pointer into a user register only if needed:

```
        call label
label:  pop %ebx
        // Register %ebx now holds the address of "label", and
        // can be used as a base for subsequent memory accesses.
```

X64 does have IP-relative addressing, so hacks like this are not needed.

So that takes care of code, but you still need to think about static data, which can introduce the need for load-time relocation even when there are no obvious instances of "take the address of this symbol" in the source code.

```
/* How many times have you written code like this? */
const char* static_strings[] = { "Hello", "world" };
```

Given that modern operating systems need to support running arbitrary code when a DSO is loaded (e.g. static initialisers in C++), load-time relocation is typically offloaded onto the DSO itself these days, with the "loader" proper just handling cross-object name resolution.

Stacks and heaps are a whole other topic, and I think that would be worth a separate (and specific!) question. I will merely note that multi-threading already complicates the picture that I think you may have in your head.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual memory is transparent to your questioning. Every execution unit (process) sees the whole virtual space as flat and is unaware of the actual underlying storage in different memory levels.

A linker can perform static relocation, i.e. assign the addresses that must be used by the loader. It organizes the global mapping of all data and compiled code.

PIC code can still be relocated by the loader, as all internal address references are relative to a base register.